Is it possible to put the FastEndpoints Group prefix before the Version prefix?
Is it possible to configure, if not, are there any plans to make changes in the FastEndpoints framework so that the group route prefix is ​​added before the version route prefix.
Now to work around this situation I manually specify RoutePrefix Override("api/mobile"); for each endpoint in Endpoints.Configure()
I have a list of endpoints for web, and another list of endpoints for mobile, I write Group("mobile") for the Mobile app endpoints, and for web apps Group("web") and also specify Version("1") and specify in the Program class "UseFastEndpoints (config.Versioning.PrependToRoute = true;"), and as a result it writes the version prefix first in the route before the group prefix, I would like the version prefix to be after the group prefix
in Programm class:
app.UseFastEndpoints(config =>
{
        config.Endpoints.RoutePrefix = "api";
        config.Versioning.Prefix = "v";
        config.Versioning.DefaultVersion = 1;
        config.Versioning.PrependToRoute = true;
}

In Endpoints:
public override void Configure()
{
  Get("test");
  Version(1);
  AllowAnonymous();
  //RoutePrefixOverride("api/mobile"); //I'd like to do without it. 
  Group<MobileGroup>(); //will be placed after the version prefix !!!
}


public sealed class MobileGroup : Group
{
    public MobileGroup()
    {
        Configure("mobile", _ => {});
    }
}

